# contentOffset of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, uiscrollview

how can i get the x position of the contentOffset?

here´s my code but that throws always 0 in the log

```
- (void)adjustAreaScroll:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    int value = [[notification object] intValue];
    NSLog(@"adjustAreaScroll, %i", value);

    switch (value) {
        case 0:
            [topScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
            break;
        case 1:
            [topScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(1024, 0)];
            break;
        case 2:
            [topScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(2048, 0)];
            break;
        case 3:
            [topScroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(3072, 0)];
            break;
    }
    NSLog(@"target position -----> %i", self.topScroll.contentOffset.x);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CGPointMake returns a CGPoint, which is made of CGFloats. Make the %i into %f.

Comment: is there any reference where i can find all the different placeholders like %i, %s, %@, %f?

i event know for what to search!

Comment: [Here ya go!](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

```
     NSLog(@"Offset : %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollview.contentOffset.x));
```

or Define as like this

```
CGFloat offSet= scrollview.contentOffset.x;

NSLog(@"Offset : %f", offset);
```